# PN532 Trying to obtain Model number of device from Felica tags

Tags: c++, arduino, nfc, nxp-microcontroller

I'm just an Arduino Uno to obtain the device number from Felica tags but the memory would just output 0xff. I'm also using I2C instead of SPI and I'm not sure if this matters.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>

// If using the breakout with SPI, define the pins for SPI communication.
#define PN532_SCK  (2)
#define PN532_MOSI (3)
#define PN532_SS   (4)
#define PN532_MISO (5)

// If using the breakout or shield with I2C, define just the pins connected
// to the IRQ and reset lines.  Use the values below (2, 3) for the shield!
#define PN532_IRQ   (2)
#define PN532_RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield

// Uncomment just _one_ line below depending on how your breakout or shield
// is connected to the Arduino:

// Use this line for a breakout with a SPI connection:
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK, PN532_MISO, PN532_MOSI, PN532_SS);

// Use this line for a breakout with a hardware SPI connection.  Note that
// the PN532 SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins need to be connected to the Arduino's
// hardware SPI SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins.  On an Arduino Uno these are
// SCK = 13, MOSI = 11, MISO = 12.  The SS line can be any digital IO pin.
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SS);

// Or use this line for a breakout or shield with an I2C connection:
Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_IRQ, PN532_RESET);

#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
// for Zero, output on USB Serial console, remove line below if using programming port to program the Zero!
// also change #define in Adafruit_PN532.cpp library file
   #define Serial SerialUSB
#endif

uint8_t _prevIDm[8]; //IDm of the card previously detected
unsigned long  _prevTime;

void setup(void) {
  #ifndef ESP8266
    while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
  #endif
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX);
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC);
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

  // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
  // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
  // the default behaviour of the PN532.
  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an FeliCa card");
}

void loop(void) {
  uint8_t ret;
  uint16_t systemCode = 0xFFFF;
  uint8_t requestCode = 0x01;       // System Code request
  uint8_t idm[8];
  uint8_t pmm[8];
  uint16_t systemCodeResponse;

  // Wait for an FeliCa type cards.
  // When one is found, some basic information such as IDm, PMm, and System Code are retrieved.
  Serial.print("Waiting for an FeliCa card...  ");
  ret = nfc.felica_Polling(systemCode, requestCode, idm, pmm, &systemCodeResponse, 5000);

  if (ret != 1)
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a card");
    delay(500);
    return;
  }

  if ( memcmp(idm, _prevIDm, 8) == 0 ) {
    if ( (millis() - _prevTime) < 3000 ) {
      Serial.println("Same card");
      delay(500);
      return;
    }
  }

  Serial.println("Found a card!");
  Serial.print("  IDm: ");
  nfc.PrintHex(idm, 8);
  Serial.print("  PMm: ");
  nfc.PrintHex(pmm, 8);
  Serial.print("  System Code: ");
  nfc.PrintHex16(systemCodeResponse);
  Serial.print("\n");

  memcpy(_prevIDm, idm, 8);
  _prevTime = millis();


  Serial.print("Request Service command -> ");
  //Code to indicate System FFFFh
  uint16_t nodeCodeList[3] = {0x0000, 0x1000, 0xFFFF};
  uint16_t keyVersions[3];
  ret = nfc.felica_RequestService(3, nodeCodeList, keyVersions);

  if (ret != 1)
  {
    Serial.println("error");
  } else {
    Serial.println("OK!");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
      Serial.print("  Node Code: "); nfc.PrintHex16(nodeCodeList[i]);
      Serial.print(" -> Key Version: "); nfc.PrintHex16(keyVersions[i]);
      Serial.println("");
    }
  }

  Serial.print("Read Without Encryption command -> ");
  uint8_t blockData[3][16];
  uint16_t serviceCodeList[1] = {0x000B};
  uint16_t blockList[3] = {0x8000, 0x8001, 0x8002};
  ret = nfc.felica_ReadWithoutEncryption(1, serviceCodeList, 3, blockList, blockData);

  if (ret != 1)
  {
    Serial.println("error");
  } else {
    Serial.println("OK!");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
      Serial.print("  Block no. "); Serial.print(i, DEC); Serial.print(": ");
      nfc.PrintHex(blockData[i], 16);
    }
  }


  Serial.print("Request Response command -> ");
  uint8_t mode;
  ret = nfc.felica_RequestResponse(&mode);
  if (ret != 1)
  {
    Serial.println("error");
  } else {
    Serial.println("OK!");
    Serial.print("  mode: "); Serial.println(mode, DEC);
  }


  Serial.print("Request System Code command -> ");
  uint8_t numSystemCode;
  uint16_t systemCodeList[16];
  ret = nfc.felica_RequestSystemCode(&numSystemCode, systemCodeList);
  if (ret != 1)
  {
    Serial.println("error");
  } else {
    Serial.println("OK!");
    for(int i=0; i< numSystemCode; i++) {
      Serial.print("  System code: ");  nfc.PrintHex16(systemCodeList[i]); Serial.println("");
    }
  }

  // Wait 1 second before continuing
  Serial.println("Card access completed!\n");
  //delay(1000);
}
```

Here is my library .cpp

```
/***** FeliCa Functions ******/
/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Poll FeliCa card. PN532 acting as reader/initiator,
            peer acting as card/responder.
    @param[in]  systemCode             Designation of System Code. When sending FFFFh as System Code,
                                       all the FeliCa cards can return response.
    @param[in]  requestCode            Designation of Request Data as follows:
                                         00h: No Request
                                         01h: System Code request (to acquire System Code of the card)
                                         02h: Communication perfomance request
    @param[out] idm                    IDm of the card (8 bytes)
    @param[out] pmm                    PMm of the card (8 bytes)
    @param[out] systemCodeResponse     System Code of the card (2bytes)
    @return                            1: A FeliCa card has detected,  0: No card has detected,   -1: error

*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_Polling(uint16_t systemCode, uint8_t requestCode,
        uint8_t *idm, uint8_t *pmm, uint16_t *systemCodeResponse, uint16_t timeout)
{
  pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_INLISTPASSIVETARGET;
  pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 1;
  pn532_packetbuffer[2] = 1;
  pn532_packetbuffer[3] = FELICA_CMD_POLLING;
  pn532_packetbuffer[4] = (systemCode >> 8) & 0xff;
  pn532_packetbuffer[5] = systemCode & 0xFF;
  pn532_packetbuffer[6] = requestCode;
  pn532_packetbuffer[7] = 0;

  if (!sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer,8,timeout)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Could not send Polling command"));
    #endif
    return -1;
  }

  // Wait card response
  if (!waitready(timeout)) {
    return -2;
  }

  readdata(pn532_packetbuffer, 9+20+2);
  if ( !felica_checkResponse(PN532_RESPONSE_INLISTPASSIVETARGET) ) {
    return -2;
  }

  // Check NbTg (pn532_packetbuffer[7])
  if (pn532_packetbuffer[7] == 0) {
    // No card have found
    return 0;
  } else if (pn532_packetbuffer[7] != 1) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print (F("Unhandled number of targets inlisted. NbTg = "));
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(pn532_packetbuffer[7], HEX);
    #endif
    return -3;
  }

  _inListedTag = pn532_packetbuffer[8];
  #ifdef PN532DEBUG
    PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Tag number: "));
    PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(_inListedTag);
  #endif

  // length check
  uint8_t responseLength = pn532_packetbuffer[9];
  if (responseLength != 18 && responseLength != 20) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Wrong response length"));
    #endif
    return -4;
  }

  uint8_t i;
  for (i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    idm[i] = pn532_packetbuffer[11+i];
    _felicaIDm[i] = pn532_packetbuffer[11+i];
    pmm[i] = pn532_packetbuffer[19+i];
    _felicaPMm[i] = pn532_packetbuffer[19+i];
  }

  if ( responseLength == 20 ) {
    *systemCodeResponse = (uint16_t)((pn532_packetbuffer[26] << 8) + pn532_packetbuffer[27]);
  }

  return 1;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Sends an FeliCa command with the currently inlisted peer

    @param[in]  commandBuf      FeliCa command packet. (e.g. 00 FF FF 00 00  for Polling command)
    @param[in]  commandlength   Length of the FeliCa command packet. (e.g. 0x05 for above Polling command )
    @param[out] responseBuf     FeliCa response packet. (e.g. 01 NFCID2(8 bytes) PAD  for Polling response)
    @param[out] responselength  Length of the FeliCa response packet. (e.g. 0x12 for above Polling command )
*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_SendCommand (const uint8_t *commandBuf, uint8_t commandlength,
  uint8_t *responseBuf, uint8_t expectedResLen, uint8_t *responseLength)
{
  if (commandlength > PN532_PACKBUFFSIZ-3) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Command length too long for packet buffer"));
    #endif
    return -1;
  }

  pn532_packetbuffer[0] = 0x40; // PN532_COMMAND_INDATAEXCHANGE;
  pn532_packetbuffer[1] = _inListedTag;
  pn532_packetbuffer[2] = commandlength + 1;
  memcpy(&pn532_packetbuffer[3], commandBuf, commandlength);

  if (!sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer,commandlength+3,200)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Could not send Command"));
    #endif
    return -2;
  }

  // Wait card response ( longer than 102.4ms )
  if (!waitready(110)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Could not receive response"));
    #endif
    return -3;
  }

  readdata(pn532_packetbuffer,expectedResLen);
  if ( !felica_checkResponse(PN532_RESPONSE_INDATAEXCHANGE) ) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Could not receive response"));
    #endif
    return -3;
  }

  // Check status (pn532_packetbuffer[7])
  if ((pn532_packetbuffer[7] & 0x3F)!=0) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Status code indicates an error: "));
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(pn532_packetbuffer[7], HEX);
    #endif
    return -4;
  }

  // length check
  *responseLength = pn532_packetbuffer[8] - 1;
  if (pn532_packetbuffer[3] - 4 != *responseLength) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Wrong response length"));
    #endif
    return -5;
  }

  memcpy(responseBuf, &pn532_packetbuffer[9], *responseLength);

  return 1;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Sends FeliCa Request Service command

    @param[in]  numNode         Number of Node
    @param[in]  nodeCodeList    Node Code List (Big Endian)
    @param[out] keyVersions     Key Version of each Node (Big Endian)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_RequestService(uint8_t numNode, uint16_t *nodeCodeList, uint16_t *keyVersions)
{
  if (numNode > FELICA_REQ_SERVICE_MAX_NODE_NUM) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("numNode is too large"));
    #endif
    return -1;
  }

  uint8_t i, j=0;
  uint8_t cmdLen = 1 + 8 + 1 + 2*numNode;
  uint8_t cmd[cmdLen];
  cmd[j++] = FELICA_CMD_REQUEST_SERVICE;
  for (i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = _felicaIDm[i];
  }
  cmd[j++] = numNode;
  for (i=0; i<numNode; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = nodeCodeList[i] & 0xFF;
    cmd[j++] = (nodeCodeList[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
  }

  uint8_t responseBuf[10+2*numNode];
  uint8_t responseLength;

  if (!felica_SendCommand(cmd, cmdLen, responseBuf, 8 + 11 + 2*numNode + 2, &responseLength)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Request Service command failed"));
    #endif
    return -2;
  }

  // length check
  if ( responseLength != 10+2*numNode ) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Request Service command failed (wrong response length)"));
    #endif
    return -3;
  }

  for(i=0; i<numNode; i++) {
    keyVersions[i] = (uint16_t)(responseBuf[10+i*2] + (responseBuf[10+i*2+1] << 8));
  }

  return 1;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Sends FeliCa Request Service command

    @param[out]  mode         Current Mode of the card
*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_RequestResponse(uint8_t *mode)
{
  uint8_t cmd[9];
  cmd[0] = FELICA_CMD_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
  memcpy(&cmd[1], _felicaIDm, 8);

  uint8_t responseBuf[10];
  uint8_t responseLength;
  if (!felica_SendCommand(cmd, 9, responseBuf, 8 + 11 + 2, &responseLength)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Request Response command failed"));
    #endif
    return -1;
  }

  // length check
  if ( responseLength != 10) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Request Response command failed (wrong response length)"));
    #endif
    return -2;
  }

  *mode = responseBuf[9];

  return 1;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Sends FeliCa Read Without Encryption command

    @param[in]  numService         Number of Service
    @param[in]  serviceCodeList    Service Code List (Big Endian)
    @param[in]  numBlock           Number of Block (This API only accepts 2-byte block list element)
    @param[in]  blockList          Block List
    @param[out] blockData          Block Data
*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_ReadWithoutEncryption (uint8_t numService, const uint16_t *serviceCodeList,
  uint8_t numBlock, const uint16_t *blockList, uint8_t blockData[][16])
{
  if (numService > FELICA_READ_MAX_SERVICE_NUM) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("numService is too large"));
    #endif
    return -1;
  }
  if (numBlock > FELICA_READ_MAX_BLOCK_NUM) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("numBlock is too large"));
    #endif
    return -2;
  }

  uint8_t i, j=0;
  uint8_t cmdLen = 1 + 8 + 1 + 2*numService + 1 + 2*numBlock;
  uint8_t cmd[cmdLen];
  cmd[j++] = FELICA_CMD_READ_WITHOUT_ENCRYPTION;
  for (i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = _felicaIDm[i];
  }
  cmd[j++] = numService;
  for (i=0; i<numService; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = serviceCodeList[i] & 0xFF;
    cmd[j++] = (serviceCodeList[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
  }
  cmd[j++] = numBlock;
  for (i=0; i<numBlock; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = (blockList[i] >> 8) & 0xFF;
    cmd[j++] = blockList[i] & 0xff;
  }

  uint8_t responseBuf[12+16*numBlock];
  uint8_t responseLength;
  if (!felica_SendCommand(cmd, cmdLen, responseBuf, 8+13+16*numBlock + 2, &responseLength)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Read Without Encryption command failed"));
    #endif
    return -3;
  }

  // length check
  if ( responseLength != 12+16*numBlock ) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Read Without Encryption command failed (wrong response length)"));
    #endif
    return -4;
  }

  // status flag check
  if ( responseBuf[9] != 0 || responseBuf[10] != 0 ) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Read Without Encryption command failed (Status Flag: "));
      PrintHex8(pn532_packetbuffer[9]);
      PrintHex8(pn532_packetbuffer[10]);
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F(")"));
    #endif
    return -5;
  }

  int k = 12;
  for(i=0; i<numBlock; i++ ) {
    for(j=0; j<16; j++ ) {
      blockData[i][j] = responseBuf[k++];
    }
  }

  return 1;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Sends FeliCa Write Without Encryption command

    @param[in]  numService         Number of Service.
    @param[in]  serviceCodeList    Service Code List.
    @param[in]  numBlock           Number of Block. (This API only accepts 2-byte block list element)
    @param[in]  blockList          Block List.
    @param[out] blockData          Block Data.
    @return                          = 1: Success
                                     < 0: error
*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_WriteWithoutEncryption (uint8_t numService, const uint16_t *serviceCodeList,
  uint8_t numBlock, const uint16_t *blockList, uint8_t blockData[][16])
{
  if (numService > FELICA_WRITE_MAX_SERVICE_NUM) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("numService is too large"));
    #endif
  }
  if (numBlock > FELICA_WRITE_MAX_BLOCK_NUM) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("numBlock is too large"));
    #endif
    return -2;
  }

  uint8_t i, j=0, k;
  uint8_t cmdLen = 1 + 8 + 1 + 2*numService + 1 + 2*numBlock + 16 * numBlock;
  uint8_t cmd[cmdLen];
  cmd[j++] = FELICA_CMD_WRITE_WITHOUT_ENCRYPTION;
  for (i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = _felicaIDm[i];
  }
  cmd[j++] = numService;
  for (i=0; i<numService; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = serviceCodeList[i] & 0xFF;
    cmd[j++] = (serviceCodeList[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
  }
  cmd[j++] = numBlock;
  for (i=0; i<numBlock; ++i) {
    cmd[j++] = (blockList[i] >> 8) & 0xFF;
    cmd[j++] = blockList[i] & 0xff;
  }
  for (i=0; i<numBlock; ++i) {
    for(k=0; k<16; k++) {
      cmd[j++] = blockData[i][k];
    }
  }

  uint8_t response[11];
  uint8_t responseLength;
  if (felica_SendCommand(cmd, cmdLen, response, 8+12+2, &responseLength) != 1) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Write Without Encryption command failed"));
    #endif
    return -3;
  }

  // length check
  if ( responseLength != 11 ) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Write Without Encryption command failed (wrong response length)"));
    #endif
    return -4;
  }

  // status flag check
  if ( response[9] != 0 || response[10] != 0 ) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Write Without Encryption command failed (Status Flag: "));
      PrintHex8(pn532_packetbuffer[9]);
      PrintHex8(pn532_packetbuffer[10]);
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F(")"));
  #endif
    return -5;
  }

  return 1;
}



/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Sends FeliCa Request System Code command

    @param[out] numSystemCode       Number of System Code (1 byte)
    @param[out] systemCodeList      System Code list
*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_RequestSystemCode(uint8_t *numSystemCode, uint16_t *systemCodeList)
{
  uint8_t cmd[9];
  cmd[0] = FELICA_CMD_REQUEST_SYSTEM_CODE;
  memcpy(&cmd[1], _felicaIDm, 8);

  uint8_t responseBuf[10 + 2 * 16];
  uint8_t responseLength;
  if (!felica_SendCommand(cmd, 9, responseBuf, 8+11+32+2, &responseLength)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Request System Code command failed"));
    #endif
    return -1;
  }
  *numSystemCode = responseBuf[9];
  // length check
  if ( responseLength < 10 + 2 * *numSystemCode ) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Request System Code command failed (wrong response length)"));
    #endif
    return -2;
  }

  uint8_t i;
  for(i=0; i<*numSystemCode; i++) {
    systemCodeList[i] = (uint16_t)((responseBuf[10+i*2]<< 8) + responseBuf[10+i*2+1]);
  }

  return 1;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Release FeliCa card
*/
/**************************************************************************/
int8_t Adafruit_PN532::felica_Release()
{
  // InRelease
  pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_INRELEASE;
  pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 0x00;   // All target
  #ifdef PN532DEBUG
    PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Release all FeliCa target"));
  #endif

  if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 2))
    return -1;  // no ACK

  readdata(pn532_packetbuffer,sizeof(pn532_packetbuffer));

  if ( !felica_checkResponse(PN532_RESPONSE_INRELEASE) ) {
    return -2;
  }

  if ((pn532_packetbuffer[7] & 0x3F)!=0) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Status code indicates an error: "));
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(pn532_packetbuffer[7], HEX);
    #endif
    return -3;
  }

  /*
  // Power off RF
  pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_RFCONFIGURATION;
  pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 1;    // Config item 1 (RF field )
  pn532_packetbuffer[2] = 0x00; // AutoRFCA is off, RF is off
  #ifdef PN532DEBUG
    PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Turning RF off"));
  #endif

  if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 3))
    return false;  // no ACK

  // Wait more than 20 ms
  delay(20);

  // Power on RF
  pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_RFCONFIGURATION;
  pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 1;    // Config item 1 (RF field )
  pn532_packetbuffer[2] = 0x01; // AutoRFCA is off, RF is off
  #ifdef PN532DEBUG
    PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Turning RF on"));
  #endif

  if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 3))
    return false;  // no ACK

  */

  return 1;
}



bool Adafruit_PN532::felica_checkResponse(uint8_t PN532_command)
{
    if (pn532_packetbuffer[0] != 0 || pn532_packetbuffer[1] != 0 || pn532_packetbuffer[2] != 0xff) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Preamble missing"));
    #endif
    return false;
  }

  uint8_t length = pn532_packetbuffer[3];
  if (pn532_packetbuffer[4]!=(uint8_t)(~length+1)) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(F("Length check invalid"));
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(length,HEX);
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println((~length)+1,HEX);
    #endif
    return false;
  }

  if (pn532_packetbuffer[5]!=PN532_PN532TOHOST || pn532_packetbuffer[6]!=PN532_command) {
    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Wrong TFI in response: "));
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println(pn532_packetbuffer[6],HEX);
    #endif
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}



/************** high level communication functions (handles both I2C and SPI) */


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Tries to read the SPI or I2C ACK signal
*/
/**************************************************************************/
bool Adafruit_PN532::readack() {
  uint8_t ackbuff[6];

  readdata(ackbuff, 6);

  return (0 == strncmp((char *)ackbuff, (char *)pn532ack, 6));
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Return true if the PN532 is ready with a response.
*/
/**************************************************************************/
bool Adafruit_PN532::isready() {
  if (_usingSPI) {
    // SPI read status and check if ready.
    #ifdef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
      if (_hardwareSPI) SPI.beginTransaction(PN532_SPI_SETTING);
    #endif
    digitalWrite(_ss, LOW);
    delay(2);
    spi_write(PN532_SPI_STATREAD);
    // read byte
    uint8_t x = spi_read();

    digitalWrite(_ss, HIGH);
    #ifdef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
      if (_hardwareSPI) SPI.endTransaction();
    #endif

    // Check if status is ready.
    return x == PN532_SPI_READY;
  }
  else {
    // I2C check if status is ready by IRQ line being pulled low.
    uint8_t x = digitalRead(_irq);
    return x == 0;
  }
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Waits until the PN532 is ready.

    @param  timeout   Timeout before giving up
*/
/**************************************************************************/
bool Adafruit_PN532::waitready(uint16_t timeout) {
  uint16_t timer = 0;
  while(!isready()) {
    if (timeout != 0) {
      timer += 10;
      if (timer > timeout) {
        PN532DEBUGPRINT.println("TIMEOUT!");
        return false;
      }
    }
    delay(10);
  }
  return true;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Reads n bytes of data from the PN532 via SPI or I2C.

    @param  buff      Pointer to the buffer where data will be written
    @param  n         Number of bytes to be read
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_PN532::readdata(uint8_t* buff, uint8_t n) {
  if (_usingSPI) {
    // SPI write.
    #ifdef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
      if (_hardwareSPI) SPI.beginTransaction(PN532_SPI_SETTING);
    #endif
    digitalWrite(_ss, LOW);
    delay(2);
    spi_write(PN532_SPI_DATAREAD);

    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Reading: "));
    #endif
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
      delay(1);
      buff[i] = spi_read();
      #ifdef PN532DEBUG
        PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F(" 0x"));
        PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(buff[i], HEX);
      #endif
    }

    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println();
    #endif

    digitalWrite(_ss, HIGH);
    #ifdef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
      if (_hardwareSPI) SPI.endTransaction();
    #endif
  }
  else {
    // I2C write.
    uint16_t timer = 0;

    delay(2);

    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F("Reading: "));
    #endif
    // Start read (n+1 to take into account leading 0x01 with I2C)
    WIRE.requestFrom((uint8_t)PN532_I2C_ADDRESS, (uint8_t)(n+2));
    // Discard the leading 0x01
    i2c_recv();
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
      delay(1);
      buff[i] = i2c_recv();
      #ifdef PN532DEBUG
        PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(F(" 0x"));
        PN532DEBUGPRINT.print(buff[i], HEX);
      #endif
    }
    // Discard trailing 0x00 0x00
    // i2c_recv();

    #ifdef PN532DEBUG
      PN532DEBUGPRINT.println();
    #endif
  }
}
}
```

Here is my output

```
Waiting for an FeliCa card...  Found a card!
  IDm: 0x01 0x27 0x04 0x7E 0x49 0x5F 0x4E 0xB3
  PMm: 0x00 0xF2 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x12 0x00
  System Code:  0x0088
Request Service command -> error
Read Without Encryption command -> OK!
  Block no. 0: 0x10 0x04 0x01 0x00 0x0D 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
  Block no. 1: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
  Block no. 2: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
Request Response command -> error
Request System Code command -> OK!
  System code:  0x0B00
Card access completed!
```

My goal is to decode the memory and obtain the model numbers and if possible the MAC address so I can sync it up with Bluetooth with RPI.

Comment: It seems to be ok. What do you want read? The NFC just fills the EEPROM of the PN532 and you can read or write this eeprom. You can use I2C or SPI, both are ok now (at beginning, not everything was implemented in the I2C library, now it should work without any problems) - it is just slower. You can not read the MAC, since the Felica card is just a memory block with the serial number. Your blocks are the memory in sector 1. You can download the TagInfo app from NXP to get more info about your felica card.

Comment: @Adriano So I'm trying to get device model numbers from audio devices. I figure pulling data out from the memory block would be enough but I compared it to the app's memory block and it seems the 0xFF outputs is saying it is corrupted. Wait, I thought you can because when a bluetooth device syncs it needs the MAC address.

Comment: Are you trying to read a speaker NFC? Maybe it has some NDEF-messages on it. To read them you need to be fast. I was never able to read it over i2c (do not forget the pullups because the arduino does not have them - or is not enough). I think informations like MAC and app link are inside NDEF messages.

Comment: @Adriano What do you mean speaker NFC? Yeah, I'm hoping to pull the Payload or NDEF message from devices to confirm the model number and MAC address. Yes, the MAC is normally before 00 in the block of memory from what I've tested out from NFC apps. So is I2C not enough? I might have to resolder my PN532.

Comment: For example all Sony speakers have a NFC, to pair your phone with the speaker. This NFC has more than just a pairing code. It contains also the link to the app for example. If you use i2c, be sure to have 2 resistors (1k) as pullup on each line (SDA and SCL). When reading NDEF messages, you are not just reading but the device need to write and read the PN532... So the I2C could be too slow for it - but maybe this is just a library issue...

Comment: @Adriano Ohhhh! That makes sense! The Pull up Resistors will increase the gain right? What library are you using for this concept? Any direction would be nice, thank you!!!

Comment: Not the gain, but will give you a better signal. On 400khz, the rising time could be too long. Here a tutorial: http://dsscircuits.com/articles/effects-of-varying-i2c-pull-up-resistors  - The library from Adarfuit is perfect :) Or Seeed Studio is also good.

Comment: @Adriano Yes! I've been using the Seeed Studio as you can see, right now I am going through the datasheet to see if I can get the Payload data for the model number. Thank you!